# Installing SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have a problem with the installation, here is a picture:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/A5bk6nR.png]

The error is:

```
Error installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell
Error 1406.Could not write value Debugger to key \Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: try logging in as administrator and then try to install. Looking at this error message it appears as you do not have enough permission to make changes to OS HKey files.

Comment: I am logged in as administrator.

Comment: Are you running the setup from a UNC path?

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thank you very much :)